# Is $S^2\times S^2$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^2\#\mathbb{CP}^2$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Is $S^2\times S^2$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^2\#\mathbb{CP}^2$?

My idea: by the product formula for the Euler characteristic, we have $\chi(S^2\times S^2)=\chi(S^2)^2=4$. By the sum formula for Euler characteristic we have $\chi(\mathbb{CP}^2\#\mathbb{CP}^2)=2\chi(\mathbb{CP}^2)-\chi(S^4)=4$. So both manifolds have the same Euler characteristic.

By the sum formula for the signature, $\sigma(\mathbb{CP}^2\#\mathbb{CP}^2)=2$. Is the signature of $S^2\times S^2$ also 2? I'm not sure how to compute it.

If so, then I think we can conclude that the two manifolds must be homeomorphic by Friedman's classification of simply connected manifolds.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: For computing the signature: It's just the signature of the underlying intersection form $H^2\otimes H^2 \to H^4$ (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$). For $S^2\times S^2$, that form comes from the Kuenneth formula.

Comment: The classification is significantly more complicated than just Euler characteristic and signature.

Comment: To elaborate, Freedman's theorem classifies smoothable, simply-connected $4$-manifolds up to homeomorphism by their intersection form. Rank (which is functionally equivalent to $\chi$, since the manifolds here are simply-connected) and signature are enough to classify forms over $\mathbb{Q}$, but the situation over $\mathbb{Z}$ is extremely complicated in the definite case (but see Donaldson's theorem).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The intersection form on $\mathbb{CP}^2\# \mathbb{CP^2}$ is $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}$, while that of $S^2 \times S^2$ is $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. The former has signature $1 + 1 = 2$; the latter has signature $1 - 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 7):

It is not even true that $S^2\times S^2$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{C}P^2\#\mathbb{C}P^2$.

Pinching to one factor gives a map $\mathbb{C}P^2\#\mathbb{C}P^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^2$ which can be used to detect a non-trivial Steerod square $Sq^2:H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2\#\mathbb{C}P^2;\mathbb{Z}_2)\rightarrow H^4(\mathbb{C}P^2\#\mathbb{C}P^2;\mathbb{Z}_2)$. On the other hand all non-identity cohomology operations on $H^*(S^2\times S^2)$ vanish identically.

In fact it is not difficult to show that

$$\Sigma(\mathbb{C}P^2\#\mathbb{C}P^2)\simeq \Sigma\mathbb{C}P^2\vee S^3$$

and

$$\Sigma(S^2\times S^2)\simeq S^3\vee S^3\vee S^5$$

which clearly demonstrates the non-existence of even a homotopy equivalence between the spaces in question.

Comment: The intersection form and thus signature already showed that the two are not homotopy equivalent, but it's interesting to upgrade this to stable homotopy.

Comment: (Rather the absolute value of signature.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $\Sigma(CP^2 \# CP^2) \simeq \Sigma CP^2 \vee S^3$? The left hand side has two distinct elements whose $Sq^2$ is nonzero, while the right hand side only has one.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic The connected sum is formed by attaching a $4$-cell to the wedge $S^2\vee S^2$ by a Hopf map into each summand of the wedge (ignoring orientations here). Suspend and consider the composite of the (suspended attaching map) with the self-equivalence $S^3\vee S^3\rightarrow S^3\vee S^3$ given by $(a,b)\mapsto (a,b-a)$, written in terms of $\pi_3$. Note that you can only do this after suspension, since the Hopf map, with non-trivial Hopf invariant, is not a co-H-map.

Comment: You can choose generators $x,y$ for $H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2\#\mathbb{C}P^2)\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $x^2=y^2=Z$ generates $H^4(\mathbb{C}P^2\#\mathbb{C}P^2)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, and $x\cdot y=0$. Then the suspension splitting is induced by the choice of basis $\sigma(x+y)$, $\sigma x$ for $H^3(\Sigma(\mathbb{C}P^2\#\mathbb{C}P^2))$. Evaluate $Sq^2$ on (the mod 2 reductions of) these classes and you see that only one evaluates non-trivially.

Comment: @Tyrone Why do you compose with that self-equivalence? I thought you would obtain $\Sigma (CP^2 \# CP^2)$ from gluing a 5-disk to $S^3 \vee S^3$ just by the suspended Hopf map on each summand (hence me thinking there would be two elements with nonzero $Sq^2$).

Comment: Why do I compose with that self-equivalence? To get a homotopy equivalent space that splits as a wedge sum of $\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^2$ and $S^3$. No other reason.